# key pair not working at instance level in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys, ftps, key-pair

I created a key pair with username with Puttygen. Public key was pasted at ssh key field in Instance edit form. Private key was included along with ip and username in Filezila for ftps.

The public key won't work at instance level neither at project level (if I include it at project Metadata section).

Answer (score 1):

According to our documentation about [Managing Instance Access Using OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin)

- Disabling OS Login restores SSH keys that you have configured in project or instance metadata, but enabling it on instances disables metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances.

That explains the reason why, when you set it to FALSE. The SSH keys that you have configured are working now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason myself: I had "enable-oslogin" metadata value to TRUE at proyect. I set it to FALSE and for some reason, which I acknowledge I dont know, it worked. Keys work now at proyect and instance level.

It would be nice if someone throughs some light on the reason why "enable-oslogin" metadata value has effect on keys functioning.